# Why do phone companies ask to use their own chargers?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charger, mobile-phones

A mobile charger is basically a switch mode power supply. Samsung asks its phone buyers to use only Samsung chargers, but the general noise on the internet is that even a NOKIA charger works fine on Samsung. So why is Samsung recommending its own chargers? Is it just a sales gimmick or is there some electronics fine-print science to it?

Comment: A manufacturer can make a good case they carefully designed and carefully/fully tested the pairing of their phone and its charging system (part of which is in the charger and part of which is in the phone.) Hardly anyone could argue with that, unless there's a leak of internal data to the contrary (unlikely.) This doesn't mean that other chargers can't work or that they present additional problems that don't already exist. But it does mean there could be a problem because the pairing hasn't been carefully vetted. If a USB type (USB-C, etc) charging cable then not so much of the above applies.

Comment: @periblepsis yes both samsung and nokia give type C cable.

Comment: @periblepsis afterall we even charge phones with car chargers, how bad could other chargers be

Comment: For mains-powered USB devices from major manufacturers, there is probably a good reason to expect compatibility between them. Enough so that you are probably safe. For automobile? Maybe not so much. There are unique circumstances with cars (`load dumps`) and how that is handled probably is more open to wide variations. (A load dump itself also varies between cars, as newer cars have added electronics to mitigate some of their impact, while older ones haven't.) So in the specific case of a car charger, I would stick with the brand name.

Comment: At least because of different fast-charging standards. It's much easier to explain to the consumer that brand-name chargers are guaranteed to work than explain the difference between QC3.0 and PD (and some non-standard chargers just add to the confusion). Besides, you need to recommend something to the consumer anyways - wouldn't it make sense to recommend your own chargers that are guaranteed to work and tested?

Comment: Why would a company, whose sole purpose is to make money for the owners, would not recommend using their own chargers to make more money? I mean it makes absolutely no sense for Samsung to recommend to use Nokia chargers. And basically, all chargers, barring custom charging protocols, should be standard and compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be, or better might have been, some science behind it.

A few years ago, when USB-C PD was not widely used, different vendors implemented different, proprietary standards to charge the phones faster.

All these standards had different names and different implementations, but at the core of it the idea is to increase the VBUS voltage of USB from 5 V up to some other, higher voltage. This allows for several benefits:

- Compensate for IR drop on cheap (high R) or very long cables
- Allow for lower currents with the same power, again decreasing the drop
- In some cases (One Plus comes to my mind), the wall adapter compensated for the IR drop quite precisely, dissipating some of the power on the cable rather than in the phone, which is great because the thermal envelope of these devices is quite small

You could still use other wall adapters, but then you'd go back to standard USB power, which is around 10 W - at the adapter. In some extreme cases, with knockoff cables and/or adapters, it was also possible to not being able to fully charge a battery in a reasonable time, due to excessive voltage drop: if the charger on the phone gets 4.5 V and needs to charge the battery up to 4.3 V, it's going to have a very hard time to do so.

Nowadays, with USB PD pushing 100 W of maximum power, devices interoperability is much better. Once you have a USB-C PD wall adapter, and a good cable, you are good to go.

I always recommend to buy from reputable manufacturers and suppliers, as cheap knockoffs can be very dangerous - not necessarily a Samsung adapter for a Samsung phone, but avoid cheap-o no name wall adapters.

Comment: Even with usb-pd there's a lot of subtly to the profiles supported for higher power rates, and for non-technical users, it's probably easier for the manufacturer to specify there own specific charger which they know supports the right profiles, rather than trying to specify exactly what profiles are supported for best charge rates.

Comment: @user1937198 what you say is completely correct, but I would argue that all "reputable" wall adapter manufacturers support the subset of USB PD that you need to charge a modern phone. For certain values of reputable, of course :)

Comment: But then they need to explain what 'reputable' means. Is that charger you bought off amazon 'reputable'? They know there own chargers are.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ostensibly for legal liability reasons, I recall Apple being investigated for the [death of a woman who was electrocuted by using an iPhone attached to a charger](https://www.independent.co.uk/tech/apple-investigating-after-chinese-woman-dies-of-electric-shock-using-iphone-5-8709864.html) which her family believed was an Apple product but was in fact a knock-off product.

It might also be for compatibility and hence product support reasons, at least until USB-C. I have an old Nokia phone that is very fussy about charging leads etc and often proclaims that the charger is incompatible.

I think this is due to the rather ad-hoc proprietary arrangements for signalling available charge rates.